# How can I see what I have `set` in `vim`?

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

When I am using vim (in a terminal), how can I get a list/display of what I have `set`?

For example, if during a vim session I have done `:set spell`, `:set wrap`, and `:set linebreak` - is there a way to get a list of "spell, wrap, linebreak"?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of commands related to this.

The easiest way would be to just call:

```
:set
```

This shows you all options with non-default values. From the [vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#options):

```
:se[t]  Show all options that differ from their default value.
```

---

Here's a part of [the rest](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Displaying_the_current_Vim_environment) related to `set` and your current environment:

- `:set all` lists all options, including defaults
- `:setglobal` lists all global option values
- `:setlocal` lists all local option values
- `:set termcap` lists all terminal options